Using "mark freestyle edges" to prevent some edges from rendering, is it possible in my case?
This is my mesh. I don't want the marked edges to show in the freestyle render pass, but they do.

This is the X-ray mode. I don't want these marked edges to render.

I am aware that I should delete the inner faces to achieve a clean mesh (and automatically solve my problem) but there is a lot of them (you are only viewing a small part), and I was looking for a faster solution.
Therefore, I thought that maybe there is a way to tell freestyle not to render them by applying the cross in the settings, like this:

This is the messy result:

I also tried switching the logical and/or and inclusive/exclusive on and off, but I could not get what I wanted. Is there any way to make it work? Thanks.

I could fix the freestyle output by cleaning up my model.
Select>> select by trait>> Interior Faces (Select -> Interior Faces)
and then I deleted the interior faces.
It was quite easy and fast.
